# angular-ng-autocomplete touch event not work

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, autocomplete

I have a problem with the validation of the autocomplete with Angular 9 when it is empty only on touch but it does not work and touch is always false.

the module link that i used :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete

here is my code :

```
    <div class="ng-autocomplete">
  <ng-autocomplete #autoComplete
    [data]="countries"
    [searchKeyword]="keyword"
    placeHolder="Enter the Country Name"
    (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
    (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
    (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
    historyIdentifier="countries"
    [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
    [formControl] = "country"
    [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
  </ng-autocomplete>

  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
    <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
    <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
  </ng-template><br><br><br><br>
  <span *ngIf="country.touched && !country.value"> select something </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The problem is formControlName is tagged on 'ng-autocomplete' instead on 'input' html tag as we generally use it.
I did a workaround using the `(inputFocused)` event from ng-autocomplete and `markAsRead()` from Reactive forms *to mark the form control as readed after the user put the focus on the autocomplete input*.

HTML code:

```
<ng-autocomplete 
  [data]="data"
  [searchKeyword]="keyword"
  (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
  (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
  (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
  [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
  [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">                                 
</ng-autocomplete>
```

(inputFocused) will trigger markAsRead() method in ts, so there I will change the touched property of the form control.

Typescript code:

```
markAsRead() {
    this.form.get('from_control_name').markAsTouched();
  }
```

This is how I changed touched input property.

Hope it helps anybody :).

Docs: [ng-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete) y [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms).